# What are other colors i can use in java? Are these the only colors?

Tags: java

This question probably sounds silly but I need a serious answer. I am trying to set the background color to a dark red or maroon color. The standard colors do not include the red I need.

I have tried crimson and maroon they do not work. I looked up the java standard colors and they do not include a dark red is there away to create a dark red.

```
this.gamePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

The problem is not the code it works perfectly fine. I am in need of a way to get a darker Red for the back ground if possible.

Comment: Java defines a set of constants for colours, but you can create any colour using the constructor for `Colour`.

Comment: See the various constructors for `Color`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Color object using any RGB value. So you could change it to

```
this.gamePanel.setBackground(new Color(128, 0, 0));
```

or whatever RGB value fits your need. You don't have to use the predefined color instances (like RED, CYAN, BLACK, or whatever).

There are docs for the Java 8 version of the class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) that show a lot of options that are available for creating different color instances.